# How to Create separate layout for landscape and portrait view in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am very new to the world of iOS programming . I would like to know how to create separate layout for landscape and portrait view in iOS. Please check the link below to view a sample image of my requirement.

https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/skype-composite-1.jpg

Can anyone suggest me any article to do it.Thank you .

Answer (score 2):

If you use auto layout in iOS you don't need to use separate / fixed structure UI.

Refer: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html

Refer:
Adaptive Layout iOS:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started

I have implemented same in one of my app.

Comment: But the management wants me to do separate layout for portrait and landscape.

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question. Xcode has a lot of really useful tools that are meant to make things easier, not completely replace learning them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good explanation about your question 
https://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started

Comment: Thank you , but the tutorial is not saying how to create a screen in a fixed structure.

Comment: @sajith I think it's there just check for the size classes, if you are using the size class then you can see in the preview that what size is assigned for the particular dimension "Click the + icon at the bottom left of the preview editor to reveal the list of available previews"

Comment: also have you heard about auto layout, just try with that, it is very easy to handle the screen for all the dimensions

Answer (score 0):

That's easy with the storyboard: add a separate view controller for portrait and landscape mode.

For portrait viewController, keep as it is.

For landscape viewController you need to do some changes in storyboard, 
Add View controller --> go to Simulated Metrics in the property area --> Hit Orientation --> Change it to Landscape.

Then you need to update the viewController based on the orientation.